# Cross-browsing alternative to text-fill to create a gradient transparent text over image

Tags: css, cross-browser

I want to have a gradient (color to transparent) text over an image.

I managed to do it using webkit-background-clip. Here's my code for the text:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #eee, #333);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
transition: 0.3s ease all;
```

I'd like to have a alternative that could work in older browsers aswell,, is there any option?

EDIT: I am NOT looking to use -webkit-background-clip anyhow, was wondering if there's a crossbrowsing alternative to it

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case and since you will fade from dark color you can consider a gradient above the text using pseudo element to create a similar effect. You won't have transparency but you will have better support

```css
.box {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent);
}

.box1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some TEXT
</div>
<div class="box1">
  Some TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I am looking for an alternative to -webkit-background-clip

Comment: @NiclaMarino I didn't use background-clip ... I used background-clip in the second example to show that both are almost the same

Comment: You are right, sorry my bad, but it still won't work for my case as it is over an image :/

Comment: @NiclaMarino share your real use case then with an image and we will try to find a trick

Comment: Here's the link http://werybiz.it/savare/solutions.php, where it says "RICERCA E SVILUPPO"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with CSS gradients:

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.btn-clip {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.btn-gradient {
  position: relative;
}
.btn-gradient::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(transparent), to(#eee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #eee, transparent);
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-clip">Test</span>
<span class="btn-gradient">Test</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I am looking for an alternative to -webkit-background-clip

Comment: [`::before`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/::before "MDN Web Docs") doesn't have **any** effect here and [`background-image`](https://dev.mozilla.org/CSS/background-image "MDN Web Docs") is **not** a solution.